# How to set ScrollInfo Property on ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, panel, scrollviewer

I have the following:

`<ScrollViewer ...>
   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
</ScrollViewer>`

The ContentPresenter will contain a control with a custom Panel inside which implements IScrollInfo. Before putting in the ContentPresenter the ScrollViewer's ScrollInfo was set correctly. Now its using the ScrollContentPresenter which is a WPF fallback.

Question is: do I need to use simple ScrollBars or are there better ways like idk "derive from CP, implement IScrollInfo and dispatch calls to "Content as IScrollInfo". Any ideas?!

Thank you guys!

Comment: you should use `ScrollContentPresenter` instead of `ContentPresenter`

Comment: Thank you @torvin for replying. I need to remember what I needed this for ;)   But I totaly get your point! Thanks again, need to check up on that.